# Make view 20 less than platformWidth android titanium

Tags: android, width, titanium, platform

I have a tableViewRow with a view inside it.

Trying to set the view to the platormWidth - 20, with a left of 10, so it's centered.

This works fine on iOS but not android (see green rectange in photo below):

[image]

Why?

```
var innerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth - 20,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'green',       
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    layout: 'horizontal'
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var innerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'green',       
    left: 10,
    right:10,
    top: 10,
   // layout: 'horizontal'
});
```

Comment: why are you using horizontal layout ? i have edited my answer

Comment: ok, so this results in what I want. thanks.  I am using horizontal layout as I want the contents to stack horizontally according to their widths.  Is this incompatible then?

Answer (score 0):

The default is to have the view centered, so just do this:

```
var innerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth - 20,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
});
```

Comment: well it depends on what the layout of the parent container is. Is it vertical, horizontal or composite?

Comment: Yes, I've subsequently found this out.  I've got round the problem with a combo of the answer above and putting my horizontally arranged items in a nested container.  Thanks for your input.